# TensorContract with KroneckerProduct instead of ordinary Times

Tags: replacement, linear-algebra

Is it possible somehow to contract two tensors, say `A={{a1,a2,a3},{a4,a5,a6}}` and `B={b1,b2,b3}`, where the elements `a1`,`a2,...,b1,b2` are themselves vectors:

```
 A = {{a1, a2, -a3}, {a4, -a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9}};
 B={b1,b2,b3};
 x=TensorProduct[A,B];
 TensorContract[x,{1,3}];

 (*{a1 b1 + a4 b2 + a7 b3, a2 b1 - a5 b2 + a8 b3, -a3 b1 + a6 b2 + a9 b3} *)
```

and  get instead of the ordinary `Times` between elements like `a1 b1` the `KroneckerProduct[a1,b1]`. A replacement rule like `Times->KroneckerProduct` does not work unfortunately, because a minus sign in *Mathematica* is handled as `Times[-1,a5,b2]`. Thus replacing here `Times->KroneckerProduct` yields something nonsensible, because -1 is not a tensor.

Comment: When I enter your code, it gives an error since `a1....b3` are not defined as lists - but if you go ahead and define them as lists, like `a1= {a11, a12}` etc, then you can't do a `KroneckerProduct` like you want to.  Do you want to make this substitution at the level on the `TensorProduct` or not until `TensorContract`?

Comment: @JasonB I fixed the problem in the question and addded the result. What I want is KroneckerProduct[a1,b1]+...-KroneckerProduct[a5,b2]+.... . The a1,a2,... and b1,b2,... are column and row vectors that I put in there through replacement rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
TensorContract[x, {1, 3}] /. {Times[-1, x_, y_] :>
   Times[-1, KroneckerProduct[x, y]], 
   Times[x_, y_] :> KroneckerProduct[x, y]}
(* {KroneckerProduct[a1, b1] + KroneckerProduct[a4, b2] + KroneckerProduct[a7, b3], 
    KroneckerProduct[a2, b1] - KroneckerProduct[a5, b2] + KroneckerProduct[a8, b3],
    -KroneckerProduct[a3, b1] + KroneckerProduct[a6, b2] + KroneckerProduct[a9, b3]} *)
```

I wish this could be done better though, since it has one fatal flaw.  The vectors in question will always be in lexicographical order.  In this case, you always want the `KroneckerProduct[a,b]`, so it isn't a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to your comment regarding the lexicographical order I now simply an A in front of all column vectors and a B in front of all row vectors, such that I always get the correct order. Yesterday I resorted the terms by hand

Comment: @JakobH - it seems to me that we could write our own `TensorProduct` function that uses `KroneckerProduct` in place of `Times`, and then we could use any matrices.